# Should $x$ be not free in $\beta$ to prove $\vdash [ \forall x(\beta\rightarrow \alpha)\rightarrow (\exists x\beta\rightarrow \alpha)]$?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, formal-proofs

Should $x$ be not free in $\beta$ to prove $\vdash [ \forall x(\beta\rightarrow \alpha)\rightarrow (\exists x\beta\rightarrow \alpha)]$?

In "**Mathematical Introduction to Logic, Enderton**" This is an example where readers are asked to convince themselves that :

If $x$ does not occuer free in $\alpha$ then, $\vdash [ \forall x(\beta\rightarrow \alpha)\leftrightarrow (\exists x\beta\rightarrow \alpha)]$

For me, We have to assume that $x$ is not free in $\beta$ too. The reason comes from the argument:

To prove that: 
$\vdash [ \forall x(\beta\rightarrow \alpha)\rightarrow (\exists x\beta\rightarrow \alpha)]$, It suffice to prove (using deduction theorem) that $\{\forall x(\beta \rightarrow \alpha),\exists x\beta\}\vdash \alpha$, So, it suffice to show that (using contraposition): $\{\forall x(\beta \rightarrow \alpha),\neg\alpha \}\vdash \neg\exists x\beta $.

Since we have $\forall x(\beta \rightarrow \alpha)$, we can deduce $(\beta \rightarrow \alpha)$, but we have $\neg\alpha$ so we can deduce $\neg\beta$. ***If*** $x$ is NOT free in $\beta$, we can use generalization theorem to deduce $\forall x \neg\beta$ which is essentially $\neg\exists \beta$. thus we have showed that $\{\forall x(\beta \rightarrow \alpha),\exists x\beta\}\vdash \alpha$ and we are done.

My point is that, In order for this proof to be valid, we needed to assume that $x$ does not occur free in $\beta$ hence we need this assumption from the beginning.

So the **question**, Do we need to assume $x$ is not free in $\beta$? Or is there any other proof for this fact without any need for this assumption (in this case, please, provide such proof).

Comment: See Enderton, page 122 : "If $x$ does not occur free in $\alpha$, then $⊢(∃xβ→α)↔∀x(β→α)$. The reader might want to convince him- or herself that the above formula is valid."

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, I've already mentioned that the formula is in enderton's book. But As mentioned above, it seems that We need to assume that $x$ is not free in $\beta$ too.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, Sorry, It's just a typo while writing, I've edited it...

Comment: If $x$ is not free in $\alpha$ of $\beta$ then the equivalence is trivial, because the quantifier over $x$ has no effect over the formula if neither formula has $x$ free.

Comment: @Carl Mummert, You are right, I didn't notice that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NO; the only proviso needed is : $x \notin FV(\alpha)$.

The complete proof is :

1) $∀x(β→α)$ --- assumed

2) $¬α$ --- assumed [a]

3) $(β→α)$ --- from 1) by Ax.2 and *modus ponens*

4) $\lnot \alpha \rightarrow \lnot \beta$ --- from 3) by *taut impl* (*contraposition*)

5) $\lnot \beta$ --- from 2) and 4) by *mp*

6) $\forall x \lnot \beta$ --- from 5) by **Gen Th**; the assumptions are 1) : no $x$ free, and 2) : $x$ not free in $\alpha$ by proviso

7) $\lnot \alpha \rightarrow \forall x \lnot \beta$ --- from 2) and 6) by *DT*, discharging [a]

8) $\lnot \forall x \lnot \beta \rightarrow \alpha$ --- from 7) by *taut impl*

9) $\exists x \beta \rightarrow \alpha$ --- by abbreviation for $\exists$

> 10) $∀x(β→α) \rightarrow (\exists x \beta \rightarrow \alpha)$ --- from 1) and 9) by *DT*.

The proviso : $x \notin FV(\alpha)$ is needed in step 6) for the correct application of **Gen Th**. The proviso in it is relative to the assumptions and **not** to the formula itself "to be generalized" (in our case : $\beta$).

If, in order to apply **Gen Th** to $\beta$, we require that $x$ is not free in it, the result of the generalization : $\forall x \beta$ would be quite useless ...

Comment: In step 6, we are proving that $\neg\beta\vdash \forall x\neg\beta$, So using generlization theorem, $x$ must NOT be free in $\beta$ not $\alpha$. Here the assumptions are $\{\neg\beta\}$ not $\{ \alpha\}$...

Comment: Sorry, After revising the steps, I got my mistake! Thanks!

Comment: $x\not \in FV(\alpha)$, what really means?, if it wasn't. The mean of the formula  $\alpha$ would change, right? is that the reason? or what

Comment: @jonaprieto - $x \notin FV(\alpha)$ means: "the variable $x$ is not *free* in formula $\alpha$". Example: $x \notin FV (\forall x (x=x))$.

Comment: Please excuse me for commenting so many years after the original post, but I’m having trouble following your proof. My confusion lies between lines 2 and 6. Greek aside, to whichever name is hypothesized in line 2, it seems to me that Gen. cannot be used in line 6 since it would have to be the same name in line 2 that hasn’t yet been discharged. I’m used to doing Gen./Universal Intro. over arbitrary names, so this looks invalid to my eye. I suspect my confusion is that you’re not assuming a name in line 2, but only some sort of “term” with weird side-conditions.

Comment: @Pdubya_24 - The **Gen Th rule** (that is exactly like UI of ND) needs that $x$ is not free in the assumptions of the proof: the assumptions are 1) and 2) and we have that $x$ is not free in $\alpha$ and obviously not free in 1=: thus, we can conclude with $\forall x \lnot \beta$.

Comment: Could you possibly give an example that does not use vacuous quantification? For example, how could I prove $\neg \exists x Fx \to \forall x \neg Fx$ ?

Comment: @Pdubya_24 - assume Fx,introduce existential quantifier, then contradiction, then not-Fx. Now generalise.

Comment: One last question. Thank you in advance for your time and consideration. 

Isn’t x free in $\neg Fx$ ?

Comment: @Pdubya_24 - ok the issue is still not clear... $Fx \to \forall x Fx$ is **not** valid while $P \to \forall x Px$ with no x in P is valid. Can you see why?

Comment: Yes, but I can’t see why using Gen is valid on $\neg Fx$ since x is free. I see that this example is proven in basically the same way as natural deduction, except that a name is used instead of a free variable; so to be clear, I’m confident that Gen is valid, but I just don’t see how to use it correctly.